# Cross slide of images in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am developing an application in which there are five images and the transition between them should take place in such a way that one cross slides the other.I have implemented some techniques but those doesn't meet my expectation.If you have any idea about it please share it with me.

Thanks in advance.
Pk

Answer (score 0):

download example application it can help you

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader